Not able to find api call made from main page in the page source
After loading page
https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/miscellaneous/aurangabaddistillery/AD05

it makes a call to ( found through Network tab )
https://priceapi.moneycontrol.com/pricefeed/bse/equitycash/AD06

But above API entry / call is not to be found in the main page's page source entry.
Please clarify this mystery, without api entry how does that one gets called and data is populated inside "Price Performance" table ?


Check this api https://api.moneycontrol.com/mcapi/v1/stock/price-volume?scId=AD06

but it is not same as "https://priceapi.moneycontrol.com/pricefeed/bse/equitycash/AD06"
